# Focus and then switching to another scene

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, unityscript, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

In this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8MsVkT_nbMQ)  at **time 0:50 sec** how should i implement that thing ,i.e **focus on icon and then switching to another scene**.Please do refer any link or tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create VR games this is pretty essential. You need to know what the user is looking at basically all the time. You could give the object you want to function as a trigger a collider (that does not collide with your player, so give it an appropriate layer and set your collision matrix right). Then you could use [Spherecast](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.SphereCast.html) (or Raycast) to detect if the player is looking at the object.
[This](https://forums.oculus.com/viewtopic.php?t=16710) reference could be useful for you.

Comment: I have given the YouTube video link , could you make more light to it

Comment: In the video person use to see the whole scenery and when person focuses on small icon in the scenery the scene switch to new scenery ...how to implement this

Comment: I assume the developer used a spherecast or raycast to detect what objects the player is currently looking at. Then you could stop the time and if the player looks at the object (the icon) long enough a function calling Application.LoadLevel(name) is triggered. Didn't the link above help you? That's basically the same question as yours: Look-Based Interaction.